Problems understanding integration in a banach fixed point exercise
I have been studying for a math test and I have encountered the following problem:
banach's fixed point theorem applied to finding a unique function
I do not get the last step. I do not know how adding a constant to the functions argument enables integration of the inside function. Also:
finding the contraction constant
I do not know how 1/2 appeared. It doesn't make sense to me.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

It would help if you told us what all these objects are. Especially $s$ and $t$ for example, since the $1/2$ almost certainly comes from evaluating the double integral.

I'm assuming the operator $f$ maps the function $\varphi(t)$ to $f(\varphi)(t) = \int_0^t{\varphi(t - s) e^{-s^2} ds} + h(t)$, where $h$ is some given function. Please, give further details on the objects involved in the question.
In the second last step the goal is giving an upper bound, and the function inside the integral is given by the following product of two factors $|\varphi(t - s - \tau) - \psi(t - s -\tau)| \cdot e^{-s^2 - \tau^2}$. The first factor is bounded above by the supnorm, namely $\|\varphi - \psi\|_\infty$, while the second factor is bounded by $1$ since, I assume (please, give further details), both $s$ and $\tau$ are $\geq 0$, so the exponent is negative and $e^{-s^2 - \tau^2} \leq e^0 = 1$. By linearity one may take both constants out of the integral.
Finally, in the last step, we have $\int_0^t{\int_0^{t-s}{ds d\tau}} = \frac{1}{2} t^2$, and assuming $t \leq 1$ (again, please, give further details), the integral is $\leq 1/2$, resulting into the desired bound.
An advice for further questions (here and everywhere else): I understand the frustration, but in order to be helped try to make every object involved clear from the beginning (notice I had to make assumptions three times, and I'm not even mentioning what kind of functions are $\varphi$ and $\psi$). Do not assume they're "obvious" from the context. It may help you find the answer yourself, and may increase the change somebody is willing to answer.
